# 'Update' and how to use variables to define patterns in functions' arguments...?

Tags: evaluation, packages, argument-patterns

This seems like an obvious issue that I have nevertheless never encountered before.

In a package, I want to use a variable to define a pattern that is used in the definition of some functions. However the actual pattern is not defined until run-time. Unfortunately MMA refuses to use the updated values in the variable, and the function definitions retain the original symbol definition that was set within the package. The function '`Update`' is of no assistance:

```
ClearAll[testF,$symbols]
$symbols="placeholder";

testF[$symbols]:="It works!!!"
testF[___]:="Failed!!!"

(*Sometime later, after the package has been loaded, a new definition of $symbols is made:*)
$symbols=Alternatives@@{a,b,c};

(* However it is clear that the updated $symbols is not being used, the "placeholder" 
value having been inserted, and $symbol not appearing at all within the DownValues:*)
DownValues[testF]
(*-> {HoldPattern[testF["placeholder"]]:>"It works!!!", HoldPattern[testF[_]]:>"NO!!!"} *)

(*And of course it is impossible for testF[a] to work as expected:*)
testF[a]
(*-> "NO!!!" *)

(* 'Update' is useless: *)
Update[testF]
Update[$symbols]
(* -> syntax errors for Update[$symbols] because the Alternatives are inserted.*)

(* Downvalues of 'testF' are unchanged, and the function still fails: *)
testF[a]
(*-> "NO!!!" *)
```

Of course all works fine if the first `$symbols` definition (`$symbols="placeholder";`) is just replaced with the second, but that just defeats the purpose. I want the `testF` definition to inherit the changes to `$symbols`.

***Q***: How to get `$symbols` to be retained in its symbolic form within the testF DownValues so that when I update from 'placeholder' to the Alternatives (`$symbols=Alternatives@@{a,b,c};`) then `testF` reflects the changes?

Comment: You will notice that the DownValues of testF contains no `$symbols`. When you evaluated `testF[$symbols] := "It works!!!"`, `$symbols` was evaluated to be "placeholder" and therefore testF is defined in terms of "placeholder".

You haven't specified what behavior you want. So, specifically, after `$symbols=Alternatives@@{a,b,c}` what do you want testF to return then? I suspect that you want to use `$symbols` on the right-hand side of your definition of testF, but you need to explain to us the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks @lericr, I have updated, hopefully a bit more clear now.

Comment: You still haven't indicated the desired behavior. Look, if testF somehow depends on `$symbols`, then write it that way. Somethinng like `testF[] := Switch[Head[$symbols], String, "it works with string", Alternatives, "it works with alternatives", _, "i don't handle that form"]`

Comment: The desired behavior is that ```testF[a]``` returns "It works!". The problem is that the definition viz ```$symbols``` is inserted immediately when ```testF``` is defined. There is no way to force it to be retained in symbolic form except by putting it inside of a ```Condition``` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps better answers will come, but I have found two on my own:

The easy answer:
One cannot use 'variable patterns' (`$symbols`) 'directly' within the LHS of function definitions (i.e. `testF[$symbols]:="..."`) because of the issues described in the OP. (What the scope of the 'directly' constraint is not entirely clear). However MMA magically retains 'variable patterns' in their original symbolic forms within a `Condition` on the LHS. Hence one can write:

```
testF[x_/;MatchQ[x,$symbols]]:="It works!!!"
```

and the DownValues will still contain `$symbols`:

```
DownValues[testF]
(*-> {HoldPattern[testF[x_/;MatchQ[x,$symbols]]]:>"It Works!",...}
```

That is, the `Condition` protected the values of `$symbols` from being immediately inserted.

The hard answer:
One has to redefine the DownValues on-the-fly at runtime. This is not a practical solution.

**EDIT:** in fact the issue is a bit more subtle: it is not just that the values of the `$symbols` symbol are being inserted 'prematurely'. Even if `$symbols` is not given any value prior to the definition of `testF` so that it is retained and visible within the LHS of the `testF` DownValues replacement rule, even then it will not be evaluated such that any current values are inserted. Yet somehow MMA will evaluate that same symbol if it is within `Condition`.

Comment: You seem to think this behavior is mysterious. That plus the fact that you reference "run-time" suggests to me that you aren't very familiar with Mathematica's execution model. It really would be easier to help you, both in terms of solving your immediate problem and in terms of deepening your understanding of Mathematica, if you would provide some context, vision, objective. I know you think you've done that, but to me you're still stuck on lower level tactical issues and haven't really explained what behavior you actually need.

Comment: Thanks @lericr, I don't think that's it at all. Doesn't it seem funny that ```testF[x_/;MatchQ[x,$symbols]]:=...``` will evaluate $symbols 'at runtime' (i.e. when applied), but ```testF[$symbols]:=...``` won't? The objective is simple, and I think it was stated, no?: To have patterns updated 'dynamically' at 'runtime' (i.e. from within a program that is running for hours and updating $symbols), and to use MMA's standard pattern matching syntax (which, if $symbols=Alternatives[1,2,3], it is). Originally I would have expected Update to be of use here, but of course it isn't.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem funny. Condition has the attribute HoldAll. So does PatternTest, so you could have also done this: `testF[x_?(MatchQ[$symbols])]:=...`. This behavior is totally expected.

Comment: And no, the objective is not clear, and doesn't seem to be simple. You've just provided a bit more with your comment about "running for hours and updating symbols", but you seem stuck on the mechanism of using a single SetDelayed expression to be able to repeatedly trigger changes to DownValues. That's not a clear objective, that's a very specific strategy for implementing an as yet unstated objective. There may actually be a clever way to do this, but I won't hazard a guess without understanding more about the objective.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right @lericr. I was not understanding MMA's evaluation: The various Hold/HoldFirst/HoldAll attributes of the various functions within the definition of ```testF```'s LHS are determining when ```$symbols``` is being inserted. But I still don't understand which function's properties in ```tF[a:$S,b_/;MatchQ[b,$S]]:={a,b}``` with ```$S=Alternatives@@{1,2}``` are blocking evaluation for ```tF[1,2]```.

Comment: Let's start simpler. Assuming `x` is unassigned, evaluating `testFunc[x] := 5` results in DownValues of `HoldPattern[testFunc[x]] :> 5`. HoldPattern has the HoldAll attribute. The evaluator uses the DownValues to find matching expressions. Expressions are checked against the left-hand-side of the rule, and upon finding a match, the right-hand-side is used as the replacement. Once that right-hand-side is "free" of the HoldPattern, it will itself undergo matching/replacing cycles by the evaluator. We can see if it works: `testFunc[x]` should return `5`. ...

Comment: Now evaluate `x = 17` and then `testFunc[x]`. The result is `testFunc[17]`. Why? Before the evaluator tries to replace the whole expression, it first evaluates the arguments. The symbol `x` gets replaced with `17` and there is no more work to be done on the arguments. The evaluator moves on to evaluating `testFunc[17]`, but it finds no match. The integer `17` does not match the symbol `x`. Remember, the DownValues pattern we're matching against, `testFunc[x]`, is being held by HoldPattern. With no match, there is no more work to do, and we're left with `testFunc[17]`.

Comment: With this, you can now try to analyze your `tF[a:$S,b_/;MatchQ[b,$S]]:={a,b}` situation. It's not a matter of which function properties are blocking evaluation, but a more fundamental matter of the rules of evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding the semantics, you want to define testF as:

> if the single argument matches the expression currently saved as $symbols, then return "It works!!!"; otherwise return "Failed!!!"

I don't really see the need for dynamically updating the DownValues of testF. The use of Condition described in the other answer apparently works, but one could just follow the semantics as I described it above.

```
testF[arg_] := If[MatchQ[arg, $symbols], "It works!!!", "Failed!!!"]
```

Having said that, I'm not a fan of mysterious side effects. If I had more information about why you're doing this, I could probably propose a more purely functional approach.

Comment: +1 especially for "not a fan of mysterious side effects".

Comment: Thanks @lericr. I think the advantage of having the originally wished for pattern of ```testF[$symbols]:="OK"``` is that it represents a standard MMA pattern (```testF[a|b]:="OK"```) and that it would presumably be faster than the ```Condition``` version of the pattern. Your design here is of course fine, but it would not seem to be the most MMA colloquial (a minor gripe, certainly). More importantly though, I would expect it to be slower than the pure pattern-based versions (although I have not benchmarked it).